# Anti Cheat Client

Tags: c++

I am trying to create an anti cheat client for counter strike source, and I dont really know where to start. What I am trying to do, is to take random screen shots at random intervals and upload them to a secure ftp. Also, prevent any 3rd party programs from injecting or hooking on to the application.

Players will run the client, log in with a username and password that checks with a mySQL connection.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks

Comment: This needs to be said: it won't work.  Sources as far back as The Art of War say that a mobile attacker always has an advantage over a static defender.  Time is on their side, not yours.

Comment: 1) Have you ever heard of PunkBuster? 2) Have you ever heard of Valve Anti-Cheat? If no, look them up on Wikipedia. If yes, why are you trying to reinvent these wheels?

Comment: Do you really think it's practical to send *screenshots* over a network and analyse them in real time? Not that that would give you all the information you need anyway.

Comment: Screenshots could be reviewed after a match if there is cheating suspected. They would not have to be inspected in real time. Also, it's not really possible to prevent hooking (unless you get help from the OS) but it might be possible to detect. Of course, as was mentioned above, you are in an ever escalating struggle with the cheat hacks.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing cheat **prevention** is a losing battle. Cheat **detection** is possible.

You could take screenshots at regular intervals throughout the match. The server admin could ask a suspected cheater for these screenshots. The admin then reviews these screenshots to check if they're valid (from the current match and not tampered with) and determine whether or not the player cheated. If the screenshots are missing, the server could automatically boot the player.

Unfortunately this process cannot be automated so a human must check all suspected cheaters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want do some simple hook detection you must detour some functions like a LoadLibrary or WriteMemory.
You must analyze imported DLL files too and imported DLL files imports too and ... too.